# Could NOT find GMP (missing: GMP_LIBRARIES)

Tags: linux, cmake, gmp

I need to install SymPol in linux. SymPol requires:

```
Boost in version 1.34.1 or higher
GMP with both C and C++ bindings
CMake in version 2.6 or higher
```

I installed all of these 3 successfully but when I want to install SymPol it say:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find GMP (missing: GMP_LIBRARIES)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  external/cmake/Modules/FindGMP.cmake:18 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (FIND_PACKAGE)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/naghme/Templates/Sympol/sympol-0.1.8/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I used 'make check' commend to make sure GMP has been installed and it dose not have any error, so has been installed but I dont know where this error come from and how I can fix that.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear you need GMP. It is poorly designed and insecure. I hope SymPol does not handle sensitive information. GMP can spray it all over the filesystem and internet.

Comment: but I need it for installing SymPol, what I have to do?

Comment: @jww what is that nonsense you are spouting?

Comment: @sherek_66 You didn't tell us how/where you installed those dependencies. You may need to set a variable GMP_LIBRARIES to let cmake know where GMP was installed. The best way to install is usually through your package manager (yum, apt, etc depending on your linux distribution).

Comment: @MarcGlisse I am very new in linux, could you please tell me where should I instal GMP? there are in different folder I think

Comment: Please read. I talked about the package manager (I don't know what distribution of linux you have so I cannot be more precise), the same thing you use to install firefox, libreoffice, security updates, etc with just a couple clicks. And please be way more specific in your questions. Not "I installed", but for instance 'I downloaded a file called XXX from YYY website, put it in directory ZZZ, ran "tar xf XXX;cd XXX;..."' or 'I installed packages libgmp-dev, cmake and libboost-all-dev using aptitude on Ubuntu 18.04'.